# An issue with displaying scaled and offset items in LazyRow using Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I'm having an issue with using LazyRow in Jetpack Compose, specifically with offsetting and scaling elements in a horizontal list. It seems that when setting a vertical offset, the elements don't display correctly and are trimmed from the top or bottom with a slight margin from the LazyRow bounds.

Code example:

```
val lazyScrollState = rememberLazyListState()
val elements = (0..5).toList()

Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize()){
    LazyRow(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .align(Alignment.Center)
            .background(Color.Black),
        state = lazyScrollState,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(15.dp),
    ) {
        itemsIndexed(elements) { index, element ->
            val offsetY = if (index == 1) 60.dp else 0.dp

            Box(
                Modifier
                    .offset(y = offsetY)
                    .height(100.dp)
                    .width(100.dp)
                    .background(Color.Blue)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Result:
[As seen in the image above, the second list element is truncated.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKj56.png)

The same situation occurs when I add scaling enough for the element to cross this hypothetical line of nonexistence.
Code example:

```
val lazyScrollState = rememberLazyListState()
val elements = (0..5).toList()

Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize()){
    LazyRow(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .align(Alignment.Center)
            .background(Color.Black),
        state = lazyScrollState,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(15.dp),
    ) {
        itemsIndexed(elements) { index, element ->
            val scale = if (index == 1) 2f else 1f

            Box(
                Modifier
                    .graphicsLayer {
                        scaleX = scale
                        scaleY = scale
                    }
                    .height(100.dp)
                    .width(100.dp)
                    .background(Color.Blue)
            )
        }

    }
}
```

Result:
[I expected the second list element to be a square, but it gets truncated at the same line.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ck3I4.png)

This issue could be solved if I manually set the height for my LazyRow. However, in the examples above, simplicity is crucial, and in my case, I cannot do without LazyRow or a unspecified height. I would appreciate any insights or solutions.